# Checking multiple conditionals in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How do we check multiple conditions in reactjs.
There's an `?` operator, but it only checks one condition.

I want to check the status of three buttons. If it is true, they are rendered otherwise not.

Example ->
If button 1 is true , render button 1
If button 2 is false, dont render button 2
If button 3 is true, render button 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
<div>
  {yourCondition1 && <button>Button 1</bitton>}
  {yourCondition2 && <button>Button 2</bitton>}
  {yourCondition3 && <button>Button 3</bitton>}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
      isButton_1 ? <button type="submit"> Button 1 </button>  : ' ' ||
      isButton_2 ? <button type="submit"> Button 2 </button>  : ' ' ||
      isButton_3 ? <button type="submit"> Button 3 </button>  : ' '
}
```

Comment: Please use four spaces indent to format your answer as code :)

Comment: I prefer the chosen answer but this will work too; I would only change the return value to `null` instead of an empty string(or in this case a space) when it evaluates to false.